# JSON Уникод

Tags: json, php, codeigniter

Добрый день!
Есть простая функция:

```
public function pages($category=0,$min=0,$max=10)
    {
        $this->db->select('id,title,showed');
        $this->db->where('category',$category);
        $this->db->where('post_status','publish');
        if($min>0) {
            $this->db->limit($min,$max);
        } else {
            $this->db->limit($max);
        }
        $query = $this->db->from('content')->get()->result_array();

        foreach($query as $val){
            $query = $this->load->module('cfcm')->connect_fields($val,'page');
        }

        return json_encode($query,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

Но почему-то второй параметр в функции json_encode вызывает проблему:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: json_encode() expects exactly
> 1 parameter, 2 given
>
> Filename: get/get.php
>
> Line Number: 52

В документации 2 параметр есть, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если php ниже чем 5.4.0 то ошибка понятная, обновите свой php до 5.4.0 это единственное решение проблемы

```
Version Description
5.4.0   JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE options were added.
```

Comment: Странно, 5.4.0 вышел совсем недавно, и вправду, только заметил в документации. Спасибо!

Comment: да не за что, просто внимательнее читать про параметры и версии.